# How does Flex 3 datagrid paging work?

Tags: php, apache-flex, pagination, amf, amfphp

How does paging work, must Flex load in all the database records to determine how many pages to generate?

Let's say I have a table with 10,000+ records and want to split it into pages of 10 records per page into a datagrid component.  Does Flex load in the complete 10,000+ records, or just some of them?

I would like to use PHP and AMF on the backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We also tried to [make this a bit easier](http://sujitreddyg.wordpress.com/2009/06/03/built-in-data-paging-using-flash-builder-4/) in Flash Builder 4 (and support any kind of data/server technology).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good article on the Adobe blog that talks about how to do that. They call it "implicit paging".

http://blogs.adobe.com/mchotin/archives/2004/03/large_data_sets.html

Basically, it involves creating a data provider that is capable of fetching data on demand when a user attempts to view data that hasn't yet been loaded.

Hope this helps!